# Unable to open admin panel after successful installation of magento on localhost in windows 10

Tags: magento-2.0, localhost, wamp

[image: How to solve this issue?.,]
I'm using wamp server 2.5 and php version 5.5.12.,

Comment: Welcome To SE. Specify magento version you are using and try to provide more details regarding your issue.

Comment: Magento version 2.0.18

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the host to the list of servers pay attention on the capital letters. Maybe is case sensitive. What version of magento are you using? if it's 2.* then you need to change the php version also. 
Other thing to check, if it's working the frontend, if the path of the backend it's correct.